# Color palette percentages colorthief

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, colors, color-palette, quantization

I am working on fetching dominant colors in a jpg image using colorthief by generating a color palette.
I have done that successfully by downloading [colorthief.py](https://github.com/fengsp/color-thief-py) and running on python 2.7. I am generating a palette of 10 colors by using the function:

```
get_palette(color_count=10, quality=10)
```

Now, I want to find out the percentage breakup of the 10 colors present in the palette to find how dominant the most dominant color is.

I understand that this uses modified median cut algo where medians are used to cut the sorted colors and then the average of pixel RGB values is taken.

I tried to edit the code at some places, but I am not sure where exactly to edit the code in colorthief.py.

Comment: May we see the relevant section of code in your question, please? I wonder if this is rather too broad for _Stack Overflow_, and it would be better as a feature request at the ColorThief project.

Comment: I tried to place a print statement to see what's happening within the code, but to no avail. Since this algorithm takes average of pixels within each vbox, i am facing a hard time to actually find the percentage of the final rgb value that is generated by taking the average. There is no particular piece of code that I am struggling with. I am not able to proceed with my problem.